# Google webmaster tools : how Googlebot saw the page is redirecting to homepage

Tags: fetch-as-google

If i fetched and render a link of my website, how Googlebot saw the page: is redirecting to Homepage how a visitor to your website would have seen the page is actual page

I need to fix the "how Googlebot saw the page to actual page.

Comment: Have you verified that Googlebot is still seeing a redirect by using the "fetch as Google" tool?   Maybe you had it misconfigured earlier but it isn't a problem anymore.

Comment: You can also plop the link into https://httpstatus.io/ to cross-check.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e1jm5a 

This is the issue. How google bot sees the page is homepage for all urls.